# GLM: rotation matrix initialisation

Tags: c++, glm-math, rotational-matrices

The basic aim of my code is just to rotate a few points around the z-axis. However, after trying to initialise a rotation matrix using **glm::rotate(m4, a, v3)** and trying to check its components, a quick **printf** outputs some 1 800 000 000.0000000... for each element. I believe this is not the correct functionality.~

**Note:** I am **not** asking about the maths behind spatial transformations. They are clear to me.

Code in essence:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    InitGL(); // openGL, GLFW..
    CreateShaders();            // vertShader: "mat4 trans"-uniform
    GenerateTextures();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    uniTrans = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "trans");
    glm::mat4 trans;

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        trans = glm::rotate(trans, glm::radians(180.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniTrans, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(trans));

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    CleanUp();
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Program works as intended when the rotation matrix isn't being used. The matrix values were checked with **printf("%f", m[0][0])** and so on. Any idea as to where to even start with this? No errors or even warnings are thrown.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this issue using identical matrix transformation code. Can you show a version of the code that contains, in context, the `printf` statement you described, and the output that your program provides when used in that fashion?

Comment: FYI: Initialize your variables.

Comment: @NicolBolas Hm, thank you for the suggestion, as well as for the fine tone and compact, yet informative delivery. It appears an older version of the library may have supported not initialising an array, defaulting to an identity matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer:

The matrices have to be initialised:

```
glm::mat4 trans(1.0f);
```

results to an identity matrix.